# Can anyone help me identify this Fabuland figure?

Tags: minifigure-identification, fabuland

[image: Unidentified]

I found 2 of them in a box of LEGO I had as a kid, it fits the LEGO baseboards/bricks but I don't have a clue what it is or where it is from!

My daughter is now the proud owner of my Lego (along with a ton more!) and wants to know more about this piece before we release it into a Geocache (keeping the second one at home)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since you like the answers, please accept one of them by clicking the checkbox beside it. :)

Answer (score 8):

This is Boris Bulldog a.k.a.

[fab2c: Fabuland Figure Bulldog 3 with Police Hat](https://brickset.com/minifigs/fab2c/Fabuland-Figure-Bulldog-3-with-Police-Hat)

it appears in the following sets

[3603: Boris Bulldog and Mailbox](https://brickset.com/sets/3603-1/Boris-Bulldog-and-Mailbox)

[3786: Boris Bulldog](https://brickset.com/sets/3786-1/Boris-Bulldog)

[3793: Boris Bulldog and Mailbox](https://brickset.com/sets/3793-1/Boris-Bulldog-and-Mailbox)

Comment: You are an absolute STAR! Thank you so much!!You are an absolute STAR! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @MrsMawbs Since you like the answers, please accept one of them by clicking the checkbox beside it.

Answer (score 6):

It's a Fabuland minifigure like the one found in this set:

[image: 3786]

Here's a link to the specific figure on Bricklink:

http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?M=fab2c

Comment: You are an absolute STAR! Thank you so much!!